# How do I add space between span in html for emails?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am making email templates so I am limited with what I can do.

I've got align="center" but I still need space between the two spans.  How can I do this?

CODE:

```
<td width="659" height="28" bgcolor="#999999" align="center">
    <span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">
    CODE:</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">BEHAPPY</span><span style="color: #ffffff;
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">• Ends 6/01</span>
            </td>
```

NOTE: I can't use margins or padding in email templates.

Comment: Try: margin: 10px or similar in the span styles.

Comment: That gives you a space.  If you need more than one whitespace, you can use `&nbsp;` entity.

Comment: If you can't use margin or padding, what about `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @sharklike I am using &nbsp; but I need at least 10px worth of space.  Not sure if it's good practice to use &nbsp; to mimic 10px of space.

Answer (score 16):

Margin is not supported in all email clients. I've also had some slight inconsistencies in padding in the past, although it does work.

Might seem like a hack (but isn't html for email that anyway?) - safest way in email is to use multiple `&nbsp;` together like so: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`.

I'd also use `<font>` tags instead of `<span>`, they are more consistent.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was literally at the tip of my tongue, but I couldn't get to it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

is padding what you are looking for?

```
span{
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can't use margin or padding.

Comment: Remember that will affect the copy and paste if user would like to copy text

Answer (score 4):

Try this CSS:

```
span{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Here is Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/84qyG/

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing this:

```
<td width="659" height="28" bgcolor="#999999" align="center">
<span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">
CODE:</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">BEHAPPY</span>&nbsp;<span style="color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">• Ends 6/01</span>
        </td>
```

Notice the subtle & nbsp; between the spans.

Not sure why you can't use margins though. Also, is there a reason you're using td? I'm guessing it's part of a table?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I can't use padding or margin because this template will be for an email that will be sent out as a promotion.  Emails have poor support for margins and padding so we don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are actually looking for is

```
display: block;
```

Ex. http://jsfiddle.net/kshreve/5jNGu/

Another way you could do this is to add `<br/>` after the closing spans.

Edit: You should also look into adding CSS classes to reduce the amount of redundant styling

Answer (score 1):

Consider inserting an empty div in between the 2 span tags?

```
.spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either using multiple non-break-space characters   or spacer image can solve your problem.

```
<span style="">text #1</span><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" border="0" width="10" height="1" /><span style="">text #2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use padding or margin:
http://jsfiddle.net/tpXF4/

```
<td width="659" height="28" bgcolor="#999999" align="center">
<span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;padding-right:30px;">
CODE:</span> <span style="color: #ffffff;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">BEHAPPY</span><span style="color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">• Ends 6/01</span>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsx/React you can use back ticks:

```
<span>{` My text...`}</span>
```

Just add a whitespace to start your text (or end your text)